# Sensing the difference of words

Tags: word-choice, difference, word-difference

I have noticed that many people prefer different words to speak about **"making something look like something"** or **"have something be exact copy of something"**. I sense there is a difference and where one word of the same meaning cannot be used another can, but I can't reveal this sense. The words are:

> According to Merriam-Webster dictionary

- **Replicate** (duplicate, repeat, make a replica of something) - **Replica** (noun)
- **Duplicate** (to make double or twofold, to make a copy of, to produce something equal to, to do over or again often needlessly ) - **Duplicate** (noun)
- **Reproduce** (to produce new individuals of the same kind by a sexual or asexual process,  to cause to exist again or anew,  to imitate closely,  to make a representation, to make a copy of something, to produce something that is the same as or very similar to something else, to cause something to happen again in the same way)
- **Copy** (duplicate, to make a copy or duplicate of, to model oneself on, to make something so that it resembles an existing thing) - **Copy** (noun)
- **Clone** (to propagate a clone from, to make a copy of, to produce a clone) - **Clone** (noun)

I've also heard the words **"repeat", "follow", "recreate", "twin", "twofold", "double" and "represent"** but I still can't truly understand how to use these words in the context of **duplicating and replicating**.

Here are examples of my own, are they correct:

- I've got to **clone** this image tonight; the paper of the original is quite old already. (to **replicate** the image)
- Those features were **reproduced** in another software of a kind. (were **duplicated**)
- I wish I could **replicate** ideas with a flick of a hand. (**produce** more of those ideas)
- She wasn't **copying** the dog. She was trying to irritate it. (**resembling** the dog)
- The statue was **duplicated** in several countries. (a **copy** of the statue was created in several countries)

And with less popular words:

- Can you **repeat** his journey on paper? (**replicate** in on paper)
- It **follows** every nuance of that situation. (**repeats** every nuance)
- I wonder if it's possible to **recreate** the act they showed? (to **replicate** the act)
- This is a **twin** of the car you saw in Boston! (a **clone**)
- Why do you **twofold** every page you print? (make a **copy** of)
- This machine **doubles** what they create. (**duplicates** the creation)
- This model **represents** the building on Backer st. (it is **reproduced** to look like)

Comment: Rather than asking how to use. You'd better provide a context. I mean a sentence or a discourse.

Comment: @user178049 There'll be too many sentences to include here.

Comment: Your errand is odd and I dont quite understand what you are looking for. About "sensing words meaning". Dictionary should provide you enough explaination for a word, if Merriam-Webster doesnt help. Try Cambridge, Oxford or Longman. Btw, I think the word *copy* and *imitate* can be used in many context.

Comment: @user178049 Maybe you are right! I'm not sure if I truly understand when to use which word.

Comment: For a general approach, group the words according to what's being copied.  There is one set of words for making a copy of a concrete object (exact or approximate).  There is a different set of words for copying abstract objects, and again a different set for copying behaviors.  And there are words used for technical terminology (software, biology, law, etc.). There is, unfortunately, lots overlap between these word lists, but that should be a way to get you started.

Comment: This seems like checking an exercise from a textbook... anyhow most of the answers are pretty good, except "resembling the dog" which has quite a different meaning - it implies that the person's looks, eg. facial features, looks like the dog, while "copying" implies that she is "mimicking" the dogs behaviour or actions.